# Cannot perform remote access to Mysql using domain name

Tags: mysql, ssl, intellij-idea, remote-access

I installed a new mysql server into an amazon ec2 instance. My instance is configured with a domain name protected by an amazon ssl.

All works perfectly:

- My wordpress is running under an https.
- I configured mysql to perform remote connection and I can connect to it with intellij using the IP_adress:3306
- But I can't connect to remotely using the domain name:
  This is how I configured the url into intellij: jdbc:mysql://mysiteweb.com:3306

And this is what i obtain as error:

```
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused).
```

Comment: I remember, and I guess, that the scheme name is needed:
jdbc:mysql://dbHost:dbPort/dbName

Comment: I try it with no result:
jdbc:mysql://mywebsite.com:3306/MY_DB

Comment: More code would be helpful. Are you doing Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); ?

Comment: I use Intellij Mysql connector. No code source.

Comment: Could you please share full idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE and reproducing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Have you point your domain to the server's IP address ?

Comment: Yes all work perfectly, my domain name is running and the redirection to https is up.